# Two data frames correlation in R

Tags: r, correlation

I need to correlate some data.

I have two data frames - `df` for patient health conditions with 253 columns and `tax2.melt` for patient's microbiota analyses with 3 columns.

`taxt.melt` is:

```
| bac_name             | pat_id | percent      |
|----------------------|--------|--------------|
| Unclassified         | 1      | 5.4506702563 |
| Serratia_entomophila | 1      | 0            |
| Faecalibacterium     | 1      | 4.0394862303 |    
| Clostridium          | 1      | 5.215098996  |
```

`df` is a data frame with patient `ID_CODE` and 253 variables

```
| ID_CODE | DIAB_GR | SEX | AGE |  ....  |
|---------|---------|-----|-----|--------|
| 1       | 232     | 0   | 0   |  ....  |
| 2       | 99      | 0   | 0   |  ....  |
```

So I need to correlate individual patient's conditions (like an *abdominal obesity* or *diabetes*) with percentage of individual gut bacteria in total gut microbiota (like *Faecalibacterium* or *Clostridium*)

The result should be some data frame with columns `bac_name`   `df_testvalue`   `corr`.

Thank you!

Could you give me an advice how to make it best in R?

Comment: Thank you, @Spacedman for correcting table formatting!

Comment: So would one of the rows in the output be ("Clostridium", "DIAB_GR", X), where X is the result of `cor(df$DIAB_GR, Z)` where Z is the percent values from `tax2.melt` for the rows with `bac_name` being Clostridium and matching by patient ID to df? Then repeat that over some set of bacteria and patient conditions? If you can `unmelt` `tax2.melt` into wide format then its just the correlation of columns..

Comment: Thank you, @Spacedman. I'll try. When I get my results I'll post my answer here.